# sigma algebra vs. topology

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

There are many answers to show examples that a sigma algebra is not necessarily a topology. In [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51222/is-there-an-example-of-a-sigma-algebra-that-is-not-a-topology/932730#932730), it is shown that *on every uncountable set there is a $\sigma$-algebra that isn't a topology*. In detail:

> Let $S$ be any uncountable set, and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the
>   collection of all subsets of $S$ which are either countable or have
>   countable complement.
>
> This collection is evidently closed under complementation.  If I have
>   a countable union of elements of $\mathcal{A}$, all of which are
>   countable, then the union is countable.  Otherwise, at least one
>   element is cocountable, hence so is the union.  A similar argument
>   works for intersections.  So $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I want to confirm that the basic reason behind this answer. I thought it is because:
 $\sigma$-algebra is closed under finite and infinite countable unions; while a topology is closed under finite, infinite countable unions, and ***infinite uncountable unions***. And it is the need of infinite uncountable unions makes some topologies that are not $\sigma$-algebras. Am I right?

Also, I want to confirm when we say "topologies are also closed under arbitrary unions", the ***arbitrary*** here means all possible unions: finite unions, infinite countable unions and infinite uncountable unions.

Comment: Also topologies are not in general closed under complementation.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. And only closed under finite intersections.I know this part. And just curious about why Borel $\sigma$-algebra is that wired. @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Related: [Can measurable spaces be generalized via Topologic spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4846766/13130)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, all topologies are closed under arbitrary unions, not just finite and countable ones, and that's the basic reason behind the existence of topologies which are not $\sigma$-algebras.

And, yes, arbitray unions means all possible unions. I don't understand why is it that you classify these unions into several types. The term “arbitrary” simply means “without restrictions”.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I am not mathematician and learn books by my own. Need some confirmations.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I'll add a bit of color in case anyone comes across it.  As others have pointed out, the difference is that a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under complements and countable unions (which implies countable intersections), while a topology is closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections.

Note that there is no rule saying that a particular topology *can't* be closed under countable intersections and complements or that a particular $\sigma$-algebra *can't* be closed under arbitrary unions.  They're just not required to be.

There is no obstruction to a $\sigma$-algebra containing a topology (i.e. $T$ is a subset of it).  In fact, for a given $T$, the intersection of all such $\sigma$-algebras is the Borel algebra of $T$.

Nor is there an obstruction to a $\sigma$-algebra being contained in a topology.  In that case, every set in the $\sigma$-algebra is clopen in $T$.    Intuitively, we can think of each such set as a connected component in $T$ (however, there also could be other clopen sets which aren't in the $\sigma$-algebra).

In order for a topology $T$ on $\Omega$ also to be a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ we require that all open sets in $T$ are clopen.  This tells us that it is closed under complements and thus under arbitrary (not just countable) intersections.   Such a topology is called a partition topology and has as basis a partition of $\Omega$.

In order for a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ also to be a topology on $\Omega$, we require that it be closed under arbitrary unions, not just countable ones.  It then is a partition topology as described.

Comment: Ah, you are absolutely right.  I was being too glib.  The correspondence is between $T$ and $T'$, not a homeomorphism between $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$.  My bad.  Thanks.  I'll correct it.