# Is every $\sigma$-algebra a Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $\mathscr B$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$. Does there always exist a topology $\tau$ on $X$ such that $\mathscr B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to $\tau$, that is, $\mathscr B$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\tau$?

For example, let $X$ be an uncountable set and let $\mathscr B$ be the family of all sets $B\subseteq X$ such that either $B$ or $X\setminus B$ is countable. Then $\mathscr B$ is generated by a topology $\tau=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{B\subseteq X\!:\left|X\setminus B\right|\le\omega\}$.

---

**Added:** This question is actually a duplicate of the following questions:

- [Correspondences between Borel algebras and topological spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88916/392689) [MSE]
- [Is every sigma-algebra the Borel algebra of a topology?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/87838/26799) [MO]

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/87888/26799) to the MO question provides references to two papers, where the problem is solved negatively. For the convenience of a reader, I try to present here a simple argument from the paper of R. Lang.

Given sets $X,Y$, let ${}^XY$ denote the family of all functions from $X$ to $Y$. Let $X={}^{\mathbb R}\{0,1\}$. For $a\in\mathbb R$, let $W_a=\{\mathbf 1_A\!:A\subseteq\mathbb R,\ a\in A\}$, where $\mathbf 1_A\in X$ denotes the characteristic function of a set $A$. Let $\mathscr B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by $\{W_a\!:a\in\mathbb R\}$.
We prove that $\mathscr B$ cannot be generated by a topology on $X$.

For every $V\in\mathscr B$ there exists a countable set $C\subseteq\mathbb R$ and a set $Z\subseteq{}^C\{0,1\}$ such that $V=\{v\in X\!:v\upharpoonright C\in Z\}$. It follows that $\left|\mathscr B\right|\le 2^{\aleph_0}$. Since the family $\{W_a\!:a\in\mathbb R\}$ separates points of $X$ (that is, for every distinct $u,v\in X$ there exists $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $W_a$ contains exactly one of $u,v$), any family of sets that generates $\mathscr B$ must separate points of $X$. Hence, every topology $\tau$ that generates $\mathscr B$ must be $T_0$. But this would imply $\overline{\{u\}}\neq\overline{\{v\}}$ for all distinct $u,v\in X$, hence $\left|\tau\right|\ge\left|X\right|=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. That is impossible.

Comment: If $X$ is finite, then $\mathcal B$ is itself a topology, so there is a smallest topology generating $\mathcal B$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51222/is-there-an-example-of-a-sigma-algebra-that-is-not-a-topology

Comment: Great question! Have a look [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/87838/40263) on Math.Overflow.

Comment: Also have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88916/75923).

Comment: @drhab Thanks for the links. I expected that the answer is well known, if not trivial.